# What happened to Java Media Components?

Tags: java, video, javafx, java-7

After researching my options with regards to video support in Java, I stumbled across Java Media Components mentioned a few times, along with [this article](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/2007/05/24/media-frenzy) that seems to hint they hoped to include it in Java 7.

This originally looked great, so I set about finding it in Java 7 with the hope of including video support pretty easily. Needless to say I couldn't find it, and after Googling around all I can really find are half baked references to crow-barring part of the thing out of JavaFX.

So does anyone know what happened to it? Was it dropped along with lots of other features for Java 7 and pushed back to Java 8? Or dropped entirely? Or is it now just been integrated into JavaFX? The latter would make most sense to me, but the latest JavaFX release just claims to support FLV (at least at the moment) whereas the references I can find to JMC seem to point to it supporting a whole host of formats.

Long question short, does anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its still there, but pretty much ignored. Much of the UI aspects in Java have moved over to JavaFX, not sure how it might be with Video though.

In reference to your question, [here's a link to the current page on Oracles site.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-140239.html) I believe it was always a separate download and still is.

hth.

Comment: Do you mean still there as in its present in Java 7 just hidden? I couldn't find any Javadoc at all for it - unless it's in one of the internal classes? If it is there could you point me to the package?

Comment: No it isn't present, its a separate jar file you should be able to download the jar at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/download-142937.html

Comment: I think you're getting confused with the java media framework? I'm talking about java media components which was meant to replace the former.

Comment: Ah, yes, I was. Apparently the Java Media COMPONENTS are part of JavaFX, at least according to what I'm able to find, (very little), on Oracle's site.